# Panda's DataFrame dump to CSV file is not decoding values correctly. It has Bytea data as columns

Tags: pandas, postgresql, dataframe, export-to-csv, bytea

I have a complex table structure in the Database, which I am reading Panda's DataFrame. While printing DataFrame everything is printing correctly but when I dump in CSV or convert it to a list (each of DataFrame row as list) I see the following data at few columns:
<memory at 0x11a2c4640>

After debugging a little more I came to know they are BYTEA columns of Postgres and perhaps the conversation is falling. But actual confusion is if the print is fine, why write to CSV is not working. Is there any way to raw dump dataFrames?

Comment: Post the code that you have tried , your results and part of csv where you have found error. Then we can look into your code

Answer (score 0):

Try to save the csv with an special encoding:

`df.to_csv(r"C:\your path\ file.csv, index =True, encoding='utf-8-sig')`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the type of the column, which holds `BYTEA` data

```
df[col_name] = df[col_name].astype(bytes)
df.to_csv(filename)
```